# setting display property in the code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i set the display property to block in the code behind?

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlHedgingTypeI"  Style="display:none" runat="server">

pnl.Attributes.Add("display", "block");
```

is not helping me ..Could you please help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 17):

You can also do

```
pnl.Style["display"] = "block";
```

Answer (score 14):

`pnl.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block");` is correct ... got it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
pnl.Style.Add("display", "block");
```