# changing display property using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [setting display property in the code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471141/setting-display-property-in-the-code-behind)

I want to change the css of a div with `runat="server"` property using the code-behind code. How can I do this?

Comment: Clarify: are you trying to change the inline `style` attribute for the item, or a definition within a stylesheet or `<style>` block?

Comment: [like this (click! click!) ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471141/setting-display-property-in-the-code-behind)

Comment: changing the display:none; to display:inline; using asp .. according to an action

Answer (score 2):

```
div1.Style["display"] = "none";
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the div an ID and add styles to it as

```
 _Div.Style.Add("Display","none")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have something like

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server"></div>
```

In your aspx.cs code-behind file, you can access the div using it's id

```
myDiv.Attributes["class"] = "myCssClass";
```

The above code sets the class of the div to myCssClass.

Check out the [HTMLGenericControl Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.aspx) to see all of the properties you can manipulate in the code-behind.